# Make touch and wheel event listeners added by libraries as "passive"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, materialize, lighthouse

I have two projects:

1. `Bootstrap` with `jQuery`
2. `materialize-css` with `Vanilla JS`

When running a Lighthouse audit on both projects I used to get this warning caused by `materialize-css` on one project and `jQuery` on the other project:

[image]

I say "used to get", because I did manage to fix it for `jQuery` simply just applying this workaround:

```
const opts = (ns) => ... // some code deciding if browser supports passive
$.event.special.touchmove = { setup: function(_, ns, handle) { this.addEventListener('touchmove', handle, opts(ns)) } }
$.event.special.touchstart = { setup: function(_, ns, handle) { this.addEventListener('touchstart', handle, opts(ns)) } }
$.event.special.touchend = { setup: function(_, ns, handle) { this.addEventListener('touchend', handle, opts(ns)) } }
```

This seem to fix the issue for `jQuery`, I dont get such warning anymore and everything seems to be working fine.

Now, for `materialize-css` I found this package [default-passive-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/default-passive-events) that (from docs):

> It basically will set { passive: true } automatically every time you
> declare a new event listener.

Unfortunatelly this library did make materialize components break for touch events because of use of `e.preventDefault()`...

Is there a way, similar to `jQuery` workaround above, to fix all the `materialize-css` added event listeners? P.S. It does not use `jQuery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is just a warning, not an error.

---

> Is there a way, similar to jQuery workaround above, to fix all the materialize-css added event listeners? P.S. It does not use jQuery

Yes, there are, actually, three ways:

1. **Get read of the warning, without improving performance**

Simply add `{ passive: false }` as third param to all listeners which don't have an object as third parameter. This will tell browsers that `.preventDefault()` might be called on those events. However, especially on `scroll`, `touchmove` and `touchstart` events, the performance increase is considerable when the browser knows that the default behavior won't be prevented on an event. When marked as passive, the scrolling will be much smoother and the perceived performance will be significantly increased.

2. **Improve performance by potentially breaking functionality**

Add `{ passive: true }` as third param to all listeners which don't have an object as third paramter. This will tell browsers that `.preventDefault()` will never be called on those events. You'll see a performance increase, but code relying on preventing those events will break.

*Note*: this is what both the jQuery fix and the `default-passive-events` package do, btw.

3. **The proper way**

The proper way is to go into the source code of whatever lib you're fixing, figure out which events might ever be prevented and add `{ passive: false }` for those, while adding `{ passive: true }` for everything else.
I'd argue finding all the places where an event is prevented in a lib is not a huge task.
You can do this in a fork, ideally PR-ing it back into the lib's repo, for others to benefit, just like you benefit from the lib itself.

---

Here's solution 1.

```js
function patchScrollBlockingListeners() {
  let supportsPassive = false;
  const x = document.createElement("x");
  x.addEventListener("cut", () => 1, {
    get passive() { supportsPassive = true; return !!1 }
  });
  x.remove();
  if (supportsPassive) {
    const originalFn = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
    EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(...args) {
      if (
        ['scroll', 'touchmove', 'touchstart'].includes(args[0]) &&
        (typeof args[2] !== 'object' || args[2].passive === undefined)
      ) {
        args[2] = {
          ...(typeof args[2] === 'object' ? args[2] : {}),
          passive: false
        };
      }
      originalFn.call(this, ...args);
    }
  }
}
patchScrollBlockingListeners();
```

The above code only "patches" `scroll`, `touchmove` and `touchstart` events (by declaring them non-passive). this makes the warnings go away, without touching third party code.
Note: in order for this to work, the function has to be run before loading whatever library is throwing the warning. The code above only patches events added after it was run, it doesn't patch already bound listeners.

**Note:** Solution 2 is the same code, except the `passive` override is set to `true`.

**Another, rather important, note:** while I can't guarantee that it will work for everyone, passing the following to `passive` has worked for me on "patching" a lot of libs in a lot of projects:

```
passive: typeof args[2] === "boolean" ? args[2] : true
```

It respects the previous `addEventListener` syntax (where 3-rd arg was `passive` itself, as `boolean`) and sets it to `true` when not specified at all. This, however will break events where the `passive` was not specified and the events are being canceled in some scenario, which is why I haven't included it above.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without modifying 3rd party code? Currently it is in the node_modules folder

Comment: Yes, I added it to the answer.

Comment: setting to false seem to remove the warning, but as you mention it is not a fix, do you know how to determine if event is prevented so I could determine if I can set passive to true ?

Comment: Can I just convert args[1] to string and see if it contains preventDefault?
`args[2] = { ...(args[2] || {}), ...(supportsPassive && { passive: !args[1].toString().includes('preventDefault') }) }`

Comment: It would be nice if it was that easy. But this is JS. You just get the name of some function, not the entire code that will run when you call that function. The way to do this is backwards. Find all calls to `preventDefault` and trace them back to where the event is attached. Those can't be passive. Everything else: passive. Basically, case 3, above. Sometimes it's easy but in large libraries it can become close to impossible, even for maintainers.

Comment: Thank you! I created a npm package to deal with 3rd parties without changing their code. I applied your proper way suggestion where I add `passive: true` to the event listeners that do not call `preventDefault()` inside their handlers. The rest of event listeners get  `passive: false`. That seem to fix the issue for `materializecss` and `jquery` libraries for me. See my answer below. P.S. I will keep your answer marked as correct one, so people have more insight.

Answer (score 1):

I created a npm package that follows @tao's **"The proper way"** to not only remove the warning, but actually improve the performance. See [passive-events-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passive-events-support)

It did remove warnings for me caused by **MaterializeCSS** and **jQuery**. In case you want to use it, make sure to read customization section to apply the fix only for the events you need:

```
import { passiveSupport } from 'passive-events-support/src/utils'

passiveSupport(['touchstart', 'touchmove'])
```

Read the docs for other ways to import it into your project if you don't use modules.